# How to put output of training script into AWS Sagemaker log file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-sagemaker

What do I need to do in my training script in order to write text out so that it appears in the log file for the training job?

I've created a subclass of `sagemaker.estimator.Framework` for running the job.   This accepts an `entry_point` argument which points to a custom training script `train_coco.py`.  I would like to insert logging statements into `train_coco.py` so that when this script is executed as part of the training job, the outputs of those statements is included in the log files for that training job.

Answer (score 0):

Treat your training script like a normal python script without worrying about sagemaker logic.

Everything you write to files while running the script will be loaded inside the `model.tar.gz` generated at the end of the process.

To save any type of file, thus including a log file, simply save by pointing to the folder corresponding to the environment variable `SM_MODEL_DIR`.

So for example:

```py
import os

with open(os.environ["SM_MODEL_DIR"] + '/logs.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(log)
```

or if you want to set a logging:

```py
import logging
import os

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,  # set your logging level
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
    filename=os.environ["SM_MODEL_DIR"] + '/log_filename.log',
    filemode='w'
)
```

This allows you to persist a file to have it directly inside the trained model output archive.

My advice, however, is to use **CloudWatch** without persisting logs files, as you can do a log export from the latter at any time!